# CXCallObserver fires delegate method every time applicationDidBecomeActive is called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, call, timing, callkit

So I want to get the timings of the cellular call that I place from my app. I get call's start time as soon as call gets connected, but i also get start time block executed when calls ends which overwrites my `callStartTime` property. Same thing happens with incoming calls as well (as you can see from the console log screenshot attached). I am using `telprompt://` to place calls and return back to app. Is this a bug?

[image: call.hasConnected is called while ending cellular call]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CXCallObserver` delegate method is invoked whenever calls changed, and is invoked once when a call connects and then later if/when that call ends. The `hasConnected` and `hasEnded` properties should be interpreted as "has *ever* connected" and "has *ever* ended", respectively.

Thus, I recommend using logic such as this:

```
if (call.hasConnected) {
    if (!call.hasEnded) {
        // record start time (unless start time has already been recorded)
    } else {
        // record end time (unless end time has already been recorded)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah you're right. This is how I did it in the end (http://imgur.com/a/4Dgza).   have another BOOL variable which I can use to mark down call states.